# How to set up .bash_profile for virtualenvwrapper?

Tags: virtualenv, bash, virtualenvwrapper

I have ssh'd into Vagrant and have a location there for my virtual environments.
In 'files' I have created a new project.
I want to be able to utilize 'workon myProject' to activate the virtual env and take to the location of the project.
I know there are a few lines of code that I need to add to the bash_profile doc but I'm not sure what those lines do.
Here's an example of those lines:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/virtualenvs
source $HOME/env_ext/virtualenvwrapper_bashrc
workon default
```

Please help me to understand what these lines are used for and how to customize them to my own project.

Thank you.

Comment: "Please help me understand" questions are very bad because nobody knows your background and how much you already understand, and no one is going to teach you from what environment variables are.

Comment: did you followed virtualenvwrapper instructions on how to set up it? https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: I agree this questions is not worded very well.  Mostly because I was confused.  I was getting the settings of my vagrant project confused with the virtual environment setup of my local projects.  Once I was able to make that distinction it was easy.  I Vagrant ssh'd and activated the virtual env.  Then I went to the location of manage.py and did, 'setvirtualenvproject'.  That's it.  Should I delete this post?